# problem wpf program in diffrent resolution

Tags: wpf

I have written a program with WPF but in low resolution it has problem

what shall i do that this program will be OK in every resolution

Comment: read your question like somebody who knows nothing about your problem, and try to answer

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that the problem you have is, that your application does not fit on the screen. What I normally do in this case, is placing the entire application inside a `ViewBox` and set the Window size to something dynamic (i.e. `WindowState.Maximized`)

Loos like

```
<Windows .....>
    <ViewBox Stretch="Uniform">
        <!-- Put all other UI stuff here. -->
    </ViewBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a decision: What do you want the application to do with the extra (or less) screen space?

Basically there are 3 options:

1. Scale everything according to the available screen space. (ViewBox is a good option here)
2. Size and position controls according to available screen space. (Margins and NO hard coded sizes are the way to go)
3. Combine #1 and #2 (more complex but might help you to utilize the available space the best)

You need to give us more information if you want more details help.

Comment: @Mohsen: You can accept one answer as correct by clicking the tickmark beneath the number of votes at the left. Doing so will give your two reputation points! =)